# "format" argument of plt.imsave() is not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html), the `format` argument can specify the file extension when it's not in the `fname` argument.

> **format** str, optional
> The file format, e.g. 'png', 'pdf', 'svg', ... The behavior when this is unset is documented under fname.

However, it's not working for me, it outputs a file with no file extension.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pic = np.random.randint(0, 256, (224, 224, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

plt.imsave('test', pic, format='jpg')

os.listdir()
```

```
['test']
```

How can I save a JPG without specifying it in the `fname`?

Comment: Why can't you just use test.jpg as fname? You don't even need format. The referenced documentation just says that `format` sets the actual format (or it can be inferred from fname). It doesn't say anything about adding the extension to the name.

Comment: @jf_ in that case I find it unintuitive, because `format=` has no purpose. Unless you want a JPG file with no extension, or a PNG with a JPG file extension... I could be missing something though

Comment: Not necessarily to save a PNG as JPEG but just as anything at all. File extensions are independent of file format, even in Windows. Wikipedia lists common JPEG extensions as `jpg`/`jpeg`/`jpe`/`jif`/`jfif`/`jfi` but those are just conventions, not strict standards. People can and do name their files with weird stuff, in which case they would need `format`.

Answer (score 1):

The `format` param just changes the file format, which is independent of the file name. If you test the file type in bash, it should show the correct format even though the file name doesn't contain ".jpg":

```sh
$ file test
test: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, ...
```

If you define the extension in `fname`, there's no need for `format`:

```py
plt.imsave('test.jpg')
```

If you want to be explicit without typing it twice, you could abstract the extension into a variable:

```py
ext = 'jpg'
plt.imsave(f'test.{ext}', pic, format=ext)
```